# Error in linking paho mqtt c with arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc and arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++

Tags: c++, c, linker, paho

I have the arm-none-linux-gnueabi in the below give path and the same compiler is used to build my target file,

```
root@user-VirtualBox:/home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240# which arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
/home/user/octane_etk-6.0.0.240/arm-toolchain/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
root@user-VirtualBox:/home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240# which arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
/home/mindlogic/octane_etk-6.0.0.240/arm-toolchain/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

Now, I need to link paho mqtt c & c++ with the above mentioned compiler path, so that I can include the paho header files to establish the connection in my trget file which uses the same compiler.

I have given the below command to link the paho mqtt c with arm-none-linux-gnueabi and got the response as,

```
root@user-VirtualBox:/home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c# cmake -Bbuild -H. -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=ON -DPAHO_ENABLE_TESTING=OFF  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/user/octane_etk-6.0.0.240/arm-toolchain/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/user/octane_etk-6.0.0.240/arm-toolchain/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
-- CMake version: 3.10.2
-- CMake system name: Linux
-- Timestamp is 2020-04-15T14:03:15Z
-- OpenSSL hints: 
-- OpenSSL headers found at /usr/include
-- OpenSSL library found at OPENSSL_LIB-NOTFOUND
-- OpenSSL Crypto library found at OPENSSLCRYPTO_LIB-NOTFOUND
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
OPENSSLCRYPTO_LIB
    linked by target "Sha1TestOpenSSL" in directory /home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/src
    linked by target "Base64TestOpenSSL" in directory /home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/src
    linked by target "paho-mqtt3cs" in directory /home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/src
    linked by target "paho-mqtt3as" in directory /home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/src
OPENSSL_LIB
    linked by target "Sha1TestOpenSSL" in directory /home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/src
    linked by target "Base64TestOpenSSL" in directory /home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/src
    linked by target "paho-mqtt3cs" in directory /home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/src
    linked by target "paho-mqtt3as" in directory /home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/src

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

can anyone help me out to link paho mqtt c & c++ with arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc & arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++?paho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that it can not find the right version of the OPENSSL libraries to link the paho library against, not the tool chain.

You need to set the path it can find ARM versions of those dependancy libraries so they can be linked into the paho library first.

Comment: should I install openssl libraries for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ compiler?

Comment: You need to install or build ALL the dependencies for the target architecture

Comment: should this be use -DOPENSSL_LIB_SEARCH_PATH to link the SSL